# Добавление дополнительных меток на график

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть следующий датасет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для него я строю следующий график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне для каждого типа поезда (Train type) в конце графика добавить графическую отметку со значением из колонки Legth?
Например, для Operation 3 в конце графика появится отметка 21:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Датасет: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ezqJdxVgJfkjQHsc15LjseKpK6jvj8lj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100335429201323787767&rtpof=true&sd=true

Мой код:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,8))
operation_lenght = df2.Duration

bars = ax.barh(df2.Operation, df2.Duration, left=df2.Start, color=df2.Color)
ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='edge', padding = 5.0, labels = df2["Duration"], fontsize= 15)
ax.set_xlabel('Duration')
ax.set_ylabel('Operations')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не зря в первом ответе обратил ваше внимание на явное создание объекта `bars` - это коллекция, по которой можно итерировать.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.read_csv("poezda.csv")
df2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,8))
operation_lenght = df2.Duration

bars = ax.barh(df2.Operation, df2.Duration, left=df2.Start, color=df2.Color)
ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='edge', padding = 5.0, labels = df2["Duration"], fontsize= 15)
ax.set_xlabel('Duration')
ax.set_ylabel('Operations')

idx = 0
for bar in bars:
    ax.text(df2["Finish"].max(), bar.get_height()/2 + bar.get_y(), df.loc[idx, "Length"], ha="left")
    idx+=1

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас, кстати, в исходном файле ошибка в вычислениях. На пятой позиции у вас странным образом Finish равно 21, а не 19.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как раз такого результата я и хотел добиться

Answer (score 0):

Значение для баров указываются с помощью метода `bar_label`. Его параметр `label_type` допускает только два значения `center` (используется по умолчанию) и  `edge`. Других значений не предусмотрено. Правда есть еще параметр `padding` который позволяет сдвинуть метку "подальше" от конца бара. Это все возможности, предоставляемые matplotlib.

Comment: У меня получается нарисовать точки с помощью plt.scatter(), но добавить подписи не получается. Может подскажете как можно добавить подписи к точкам?